# Django form template without Submit button

Tags: django, templates

So I am trying to save a form without using dedicated submit button in form div;

```
<div class="col-lg-8 mt-5 cart-wrap ftco-animate">
    <form method="post" id="my_form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="cart-total mb-3">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                {{ note|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The button that I am using to trigger to save the form is at the bottom of page and like below:

```
<p>
<a href="{% url 'precheckout-view' %}" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-4" type="submit" id="my_button" onclick="document.getElementById('my_form').submit()">Proceed to Checkout</a>
</p>
```

However the onclick doesn't trigger the form and the form doesn't save. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may simply change forms.py:

```
class Search(forms.Form):
    field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES,
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'submit();'}))
```

Comment: This is my forms.py:

class NoteOption(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['note']

Comment: You can use also jquery in your template like this:

$('#search_field').change(function(){
    $('#your_form').submit()
});

Comment: I tried your first solution and it somehow helped however, the problem is that now I have to click twice on "Proceed to Checkout" button to direct me to the next step. I think the first step is to save the form field and the second time is the real direct click. Do you know how to combine both these two steps?